# Can jdk XPath search through custom document

Tags: xpath, xpathnavigator

Is it possible to look through **custom document** and find **custom object** by using JDK's XPath?

If I am right class org.jaxen.DefaultNavigator is used for that purpose in Jaxen. Also C#'s XPathNavigator.

Does Java's XPath have something similar?

e.g.

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
MyOwnNodeList nodeList = (MyOwnNodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[@Id='id']", myOwnDocumentTree, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: I don't understand you very well. What do you exactly mean by "custom" document? You simply want to pass it's name to a function?

Comment: Sorry, by custom document I mean not org.w3c.dom.Node but my own MyNode object which contains children

Comment: Aah, now I get it :-)